# Create a pop up that displays once shiny app accessed that welcomes the user to the dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, popup

Is it possible to create a popup that will welcome a user once they have accessed a shiny dashboard? Additionally, I would like for them to be able to lick a button within the popup window that would close it.

Ideally the pop up would say something along the lines of "Welcome to the _______ Dashboard! If you are ready to continue, press okay!". And the okay button would close the pop up window.

Comment: Can this : https://deanattali.com/blog/shinyalert-package/ help you? If not, what code have you already try?

Comment: I have tried this code and it works except for the pop up being present when the application is opened, rather than having to press a button for the pop up to appear. ( I want it to be there when the application is accessed without having to press a button).

Comment: Oh sorry I read your question too fast.

Comment: Noo worries!!!!

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326110/r-shiny-popup-window-before-app or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985684/r-shiny-present-a-shinybs-modal-popup-on-page-visit-no-user-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from @Gainz' comment, you can use `shinyalert`, or any other method of showing a modal e.g. `showModal(modalDialog(...))`.

If you call this inside the server function of your app (without an `observe` or `observeEvent`, just as-is), then it will run once per user-session.

Minimal example below:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyalert()

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  shinyalert("Welcome", "Welcome to the ___ Dashboard!", type = "info")

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```